# Add custom layout for MDX in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

On my Next.js site, I want both MDX and TypeScript-React pages. The MDX pages should automatically be rendered in a default layout (e.g. styles applied, header/footer) to make it easier for non-technical users to add pages. The TypeScript-React pages shouldn't have any default layouts applied, as I want full customizability on them.

What I've tried:

- Reviewing the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/using-mdx#layouts) and [some tutorials](https://www.codeconcisely.com/posts/nextjs-mdx/#using-a-common-layout-component-with-nextmdx), which suggest adding an export at the bottom of each MDX post like `export default ({ children }) => <MyLayoutComponent>{children}</MyLayoutComponent>`. However, this doesn't meet the criteria of being easy for non-technical users to add pages above.
- Adding the layout to `_app.tsx`, as suggested by [some tutorials](https://blog.logrocket.com/create-next-js-mdx-blog/#creating-layout). However, this then updates all my pages so I don't get full customizability on my TypeScript-React pages.
- Looking into the new beta app folders. Unfortunately, [MDX isn't yet properly supported with the new beta app folders](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42153), so solutions involving them don't seem relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by detecting whether something is an MDX component in your `_app.tsx` and then rendering conditionally on this.

### Detecting the MDX component

Natively, the `MDXContent` component should be rendered when you have an MDX page. In production, function names are minified though so we can't use `Component.name`. As a workaround, you can add my custom plugin [`recma-mdx-displayname`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recma-mdx-displayname) so the generated code produced by MDX `@next/mdx` is given a `displayName` attribute of `MDXContent`.
Install the plugin:

```bash
npm install recma-mdx-displayname
```

Enable it in your `next.config.js`:

```js
const withMDX = require("@next/mdx")({
  options: {
    // add it here!
    recmaPlugins: [require("recma-mdx-displayname")]
  }
})

const nextConfig = {
  pageExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "md", "mdx"],
}

module.exports = withMDX(nextConfig)
```

Use the `.displayName` property to test components, for example in `_app.tsx`:

```
import "../styles/globals.css"
import type { AppProps } from "next/app"

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  // Use Component.displayName to check for MDXContent
  // MDX pages have default styles applied and a header
  if (Component.displayName === "MDXContent") {
    return (
      <div className="mdx-content">
        <header>
          <h1>My blog</h1>
        </header>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  // Other pages are rendered directly
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

Comment: Does it work with MarkdocComponents?

Comment: @Hvitis Unfortunately this only works with MDXContent elements, because the plugin recma-mdx-displayname only works with MDX as it is a recma plugin.

You can have a look at the code for the plugin to see if you can modify it to work with MarkdocComponents, but I think it would require significant changes: https://github.com/domdomegg/recma-mdx-displayname